# Flutter: Show data in the real time

Tags: flutter, api, rest, websocket, long-polling

I'm developing an app that shows the score of sports-related matches in real-time. I'm using an API (JSON format) to fetch the score and to do this, I'm using a stream builder to stream the score and using a timer to call the API after every 5 seconds, so I can always show the updated score without user-initiated refresh

But I think this is not an efficient way from the perspective of the server and secondly, if I go with a paid API that provides limited no. of requests, then I would exceed the no. of API requests very shortly. So what is the better way to do it?

and one last question, this question may sound silly, so pardon me. If I go with a paid API that provides limited no. of request (Let's say 1000 API requests per hour)

and assume, 10 users are using my application to see the score, does that mean 10 API request would be deducted after a specified time period (5 seconds), or would it be considered only one?

Comment: Have you tried Firebase firestore as it is a realtime database the changes will reflect every time you make any changes and you don't need any  multiple api calls. Just a suggestion as you are paying check the firebase plans as well.

Comment: There are some suggested backend from the link : https://geekflare.com/backend-solutions-for-web-and-mobile-apps/

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my question. I'm going to use a paid API that would provide me with the score of the sports-related game. I'm not going to manually update the score (Instead of doing it manually, relying on the paid API)

Comment: Currently, I'm using a timer method to hit the API after 5 seconds to see if any changes happen in the score, So I'm looking for a better approach to do it

Comment: Did a little bit of research and found out that there is something called WebSocket that provides a two-way connection but In my case, it wouldn't work because the paid API that I'm using doesn't support WebSocket and could you please answer my last question (the silly one, haha)@SagarAcharya

Comment: or maybe I'm the one who misunderstood your answer. Are you suggesting to me that fetch the score from paid API and then store it in the Firebase. After doing all of this, fetch the score from the database and show it to the user in the application (this way, all users wouldn't directly be calling the API, Instead they would fetch it from the firebase database), did I get it correctly? @SagarAcharya

Comment: Yes you can use websocket as well, but firebase does have the cloud functions that can update the data in data base. It was just a suggestion. Websocket can be prefered way for your usecase

Comment: You probably should cache the api result in your own backend or firebase. But only if your api provider allowed it.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, the API that I'm using does not support the WebSocket server. Probably I will look for other API that supports WebSocket technology but I guess, I found a solution for other problems that I was facing (the one that you suggested to me, store the paid API data in the database and then fetch it from there, this way, application users wouldn't be directly calling the API) Thank you for your help @SagarAcharya

Comment: Why wouldn't my API provider allow it? I don't think there is anything wrong if I serve the data through the database Instead of users calling the API multiple times. I have limited API requests, so it is cost-effective way too@ישואוהבאותך

Comment: If you don't mind, could you refer me to any resource or link where it is been taught how to insert external API responses into the firebase (periodically)? I'm relatively new to Firebase! or probably I could serve API data through the MYSQL database (I'm familiar with MYSQL, that's why considering it) @SagarAcharya

Comment: Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSDHdWrSqLY just a refrence